# How to use user-defined input for column name in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am looking to understand how to use a user-defined variable within a column name. I am using pandas. I have a dataframe with several columns that are in the same format, but the code will be run against the different column names. I don't want to have to put in the different column names each time when only the first part of the name actually changes.

For example,

```
df['input_same_same']
```

Where the code will call out different columns where only the first part of the column is different and the rest remains the same.

Is it possible to do something along the lines of:

```
vari='cats' (and the next time I run I can input dogs, pigs, etc)
```

for

```
df['vari_count_litter']
```

I have tried using %s within the column name but that doesn't work.

I'd appreciate any insight or understanding how this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: You can index the columns by passing the column name so you can either filter the colums first and operate on them or build a string and operate on those columns, you need to provide more info though

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you could do `df[vari+'_count_litter']`.  However, you may be better off using a MultiIndex that would let you do `df[vari, 'count_litter']`.  It's difficult to say how to set it up without know what your data structure is and how you want to access it.